# How to Display DIV Contents Based Upon Visibility of Another DIV Contents

Tags: javascript, html, button, visibility

I have the following DIV elements shown together on a page:

```
<div><a href="javascript:;" id="awesome-button" style="visibility:hidden">This Link Shows Up First</a></div>

<div style="display:none; id:showUpAfterAwesomeButtonIsClicked;"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="someFunction();">This is the value that should show up after the link above is clicked.</a></div>
```

As you can see, the `This Link Shows Up First` text is displayed initially at page load.  I have the following javascript which determines if the user has clicked the `This Link Shows Up First` text.  The goal is to display the `This is the value that should show up after the link above is clicked` div if the `awesome-button` is hidden.

```
custom.valueAwesome = function() {
var awesomeButton = document.getElementById('awesome-button');
awesomeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("showUpAfterAwesomeButtonIsClicked").style.display = '';
gadash.executeCommandQueue();
};
```

I have tested this script and it is successfully changing the state of the `showUpAfterAwesomeButtonIsClicked` link to hidden when the user click on the link.  This leads me to believe that the connection that needs to be updated has to do with this line:

`document.getElementById("showUpAfterAwesomeButtonIsClicked").style.display = '';`

I have tried several variations of this line.  Is there a better way to achieve this result?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set an id attribute in CSS. It actually needs to be an attribute on the xml tag.
Change

```
<div style="display:none; id:showUpAfterAwesomeButtonIsClicked;">
```

to

```
<div id="showUpAfterAwesomeButtonIsClicked" style="display:none; ">
```

This will allow your document.getElementById to actually select it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense.  I tried adjusting the `id` value as you noted, but the `display` is not changing.  Should I write a separate javascript function for this?

Comment: Got it!  I had to make a few script adjustments, but your answer definitely pointed me in the right direction so I am awarding.  Much appreciated :)